# best material for sticking power electronic devices into the heat sink

Tags: paste

what is the best material for sticking power electronic devices into the heat sink.

We are using of Heat-resistant silicone paste similar to this photo:

[image]

thanks a lot

Comment: Google "thermal adhesive".

Comment: Vegemite :^) http://www.dansdata.com/goop.htm

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, I thought the article would be non-serious. But actually, that is a decent article. Thanks for posting! OP should definitely read it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the uses you want to do with the paste?
Given your constraints, there's an excellent article at http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/thermal-paste-performance-benchmark,3616-5.html

For the sake of having something easy to use, you can use a Thermal Adhesive Tape Pad, if you don't mind the compromise in thermal conductivity.

Comment: The Arctic Silver adhesive has a much larger quoted thermal conductivity than any other comparable product, which makes it seem suspicious. Lately they seem to have removed any concrete statement of the conductivity from their website, but I think the real value should probably be closer to 1 than to 10 W/m/K. EPO-TEK H74 is a good product although perhaps overkill for this application.